# Creating a file and replacing variables in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, variable

Background:
I created a VPN service for myself. I have a lot of time on my hands and I enjoy the challenge of creating "business like" services, so I can kind of create a portfolio for myself. I created this script to create a client profile for OpenVPN and want to clean it up. It is sloppy, but I am working on cleaning it up now that it works.

My question:
I want to create a pre-determined file for a client to use. Certain data in it has to be added to it, based on previous variables.

The current script:

```
#!/bin/bash

### Set PATH ###
BACKUP=/var/BACKUPS
OVPN=/etc/openvpn/
CA=/etc/openvpn/ca.crt
RSA=/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa
KEYS=/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys
HTML=/var/dir/for/user/dl

### Move to working directory ###
cd $RSA

### Trial/30 day/90 day/365 day ###
PS3='What kind of subscriber is being created?: '
options=("7 Day Trial" "30 Day Subscriber" "90 Day Subscriber" "1 Year Subscriber" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "7 Day Trial")
            echo -e "You have selected 7 day trial.\nUsing vars7."
            source ./vars7
            break
            ;;
        "30 Day Subscriber")
            echo -e "You have selected 30 day subscriber.\nUsing vars30."
            source ./vars30
            break
            ;;
        "90 Day Subscriber")
            echo -e "You have selected 90 day subscriber.\nUsing vars90."
            source ./vars90
            break
            ;;
        "1 Year Subscriber")
            echo -e "You have selected 1 year subscriber.\nUsing vars365."
            source ./vars365
            break
            ;;
        "Quit")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo invalid option;;
    esac
done

### Catch input for user and build/sign keys and certificates ###
echo "Please enter the user's name:"
read USER
echo "Starting process now..." 
./build-key $USER

### Set new PATHs ###
BASECRT=$(sed -n 68,97p $KEYS/$USER.crt)
BASECA=$(cat $CA)
BASEKEY=$(cat $KEYS/$USER.key)

### create stream-lined option file ###
cat > $OVPN/$USER.ovpn <<EOF
client
;dev tap
dev tun
;proto tcp
proto udp
remote SERVER 1194
remote SERVER 1194
remote-random
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
;user nobody
;group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
;http-proxy-retry # retry on connection failures
;http-proxy [proxy server] [proxy port #]
;mute-replay-warnings
ca ca.crt
cert $USER.crt
key $USER.key
ns-cert-type server
;tls-auth ta.key 1
;cipher x
comp-lzo
verb 3
;mute 20
<ca>
$BASECA
</ca>
<cert>
$BASECRT
</cert>
<key>
$BASEKEY
</key>

EOF

### Make Directories needed ###
mkdir $HTML/$USER
mkdir $BACKUP/$USER
mkdir $HTML/$USER/keys

### Store Backups ###
cp $KEYS/$USER.* $BACKUP/$USER
cp $OVPN/$USER.ovpn $BACKUP/$USER
tar -czvf $BACKUP/$USER.tar.gz $BACKUP/$USER

### Move keys and options to user's directory for download ###
cp $KEYS/$USER.* $HTML/$USER/keys
cp $OVPN/$USER.ovpn $HTML/$USER
cp $CA $HTML/$USER/keys
chmod 755 $HTML/$USER/*
```

I had used `cat > $OVPN/$USER.ovpn << EOF` to create the stream-lined `USER.ovpn`. `$BASECRT`, `$BASEKEY`, etc are replaced with their respective files encoded in base64.

I want to get rid of this massive block of text from my script. I've toyed with using `cat < shellfile > Newfile` — but this does not replace the variables, and instead adds them to the new file as `$BASECRT`, etc

Now, I *could* use 'sed' to read the first bunch of lines outputted into the client file, cat append to the client file, then sed the next few lines, repeat this process until I get the completed client file.

But there has to be an easier and cleaner way to do this. I've never had to create a long file like this. Thank you. :)

Comment: Seriously?  You’re posting a 112-line script? Trim the fluff (nobody cares whether you have a lot of time on your hands), trim the script to 30 lines or less, and *explain* more clearly what you’re trying to do and what your problem is.

Comment: Wasting my breath.   OP hasn’t been around in over 2½ years.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `source` command, put the *create stream-lined option file* commands into a separate file, and *source* it into the main script when all the variables used has been assigned,

```bash
# USER.ovpn 

### create stream-lined option file ###
cat > $OVPN/$USER.ovpn <<EOF
client
;dev tap
dev tun
;proto tcp
proto udp
remote SERVER 1194
remote SERVER 1194
remote-random
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
;user nobody
;group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
;http-proxy-retry # retry on connection failures
;http-proxy [proxy server] [proxy port #]
;mute-replay-warnings
ca ca.crt
cert $USER.crt
key $USER.key
ns-cert-type server
;tls-auth ta.key 1
;cipher x
comp-lzo
verb 3
;mute 20
<ca>
$BASECA
</ca>
<cert>
$BASECRT
</cert>
<key>
$BASEKEY
</key>

EOF
```

Your main script could then do,

```bash
#!/bin/bash

### Set PATH ###
BACKUP=/var/BACKUPS
OVPN=/etc/openvpn/
CA=/etc/openvpn/ca.crt
RSA=/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa
KEYS=/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys
HTML=/var/dir/for/user/dl

### Move to working directory ###
cd $RSA

### Trial/30 day/90 day/365 day ###
PS3='What kind of subscriber is being created?: '
options=("7 Day Trial" "30 Day Subscriber" "90 Day Subscriber" "1 Year Subscriber" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "7 Day Trial")
            echo -e "You have selected 7 day trial.\nUsing vars7."
            source ./vars7
            break
            ;;
        "30 Day Subscriber")
            echo -e "You have selected 30 day subscriber.\nUsing vars30."
            source ./vars30
            break
            ;;
        "90 Day Subscriber")
            echo -e "You have selected 90 day subscriber.\nUsing vars90."
            source ./vars90
            break
            ;;
        "1 Year Subscriber")
            echo -e "You have selected 1 year subscriber.\nUsing vars365."
            source ./vars365
            break
            ;;
        "Quit")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo invalid option;;
    esac
done

### Catch input for user and build/sign keys and certificates ###
echo "Please enter the user's name:"
read USER
echo "Starting process now..." 
./build-key $USER

### Set new PATHs ###
BASECRT=$(sed -n 68,97p $KEYS/$USER.crt)
BASECA=$(cat $CA)
BASEKEY=$(cat $KEYS/$USER.key)

### create stream-lined option file ###

source USER.ovpn     # ". USER.ovpn" also works

### Make Directories needed ###
mkdir $HTML/$USER
mkdir $BACKUP/$USER
mkdir $HTML/$USER/keys

### Store Backups ###
cp $KEYS/$USER.* $BACKUP/$USER
cp $OVPN/$USER.ovpn $BACKUP/$USER
tar -czvf $BACKUP/$USER.tar.gz $BACKUP/$USER

### Move keys and options to user's directory for download ###
cp $KEYS/$USER.* $HTML/$USER/keys
cp $OVPN/$USER.ovpn $HTML/$USER
cp $CA $HTML/$USER/keys
chmod 755 $HTML/$USER/*
I had used cat > $OVPN/$USER.ovpn
```

Comment: Thanks. Using cat > /path/file <<EOF xxxxxxxxxxx EOF works to create a file in /path/file with variables being used